# Fetching the last 3 rows in mysql in ascending order

Tags: mysql

I have a table named comments.I want to retrieve the last 3 rows in the ascending order of time.The following query fetches it in the descending order of time.What should I do to get the desired result?

```
select * from comments where id=1 order by time desc limit 0,3
```

Comment: Replace "desc" with "asc"

Comment: this will then show only the top 3 rows. I want the last 3 rows instead. @Ashalynd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*
      from comments c
      where id = 1
      order by time desc
      limit 0, 3
     ) c
order by time asc;
```